# How to append NLS_COMP to Linguistic as query specific

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Is there any wasy to specify within a query in oracle or setting them through Hibernate in java??? I want both the conditions to be made only for ONE query. Not session wise.

> NLS_SORT=FRENCH_AI 
>   and 
>   NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Oracle documentation these are session variables so the only way I see how you could obtain the desired result would to get a connection, set the desired values with alter session statements, execute your query, then set back the original values.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the prompt reply. Is there any way I can set them in Hibernate if you are familiar with Hibernate??

Comment: You can use `Session.doWork(Work)` to execute jdbc queries on the connection used by the session. You will will have to call `doWork` to set the session variables before executing your Hibernate query and call it after to reset them